# Magento Automatic Shopping Cart Promotions not working

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I have installed a "Giftcard" module in Magento 1.9. and due to this Magento's Automatic shipping promotions are not being applied. but when I remove this code from this module's

> config.xml

```
        <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <gift_card_total>
                    <class>giftcard/sales_quote_total_giftcard</class>
                    <after>discount,tax</after>
                    <before>grand_total</before>
                </gift_card_total>
            </totals>
        </quote>
```

Shopping cart's Automatic promotions start working, but this module stops working. how to make these two work together.